# .Net How To Display The Column Value Belonging To That Row Only In A Text Box After Selecting The Value In Combo Box In Parse.com

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, parse-platform

I Am Using Parse.Com I Manage To Grab Just One Column Of Data From The Parse Database To Be Displayed Onto My ComboBox Thanks To A One Person That Posted The Code On Parse Blog. But However What I Am Trying Now Is When User Select The Value In The ComboBox It Should Display Another Column Which Belongs To The That Selected Value.

The Keys In My Parse.com Database Is binLocation(values in this key is display at combobox) And binHeight(values in this key will be display once binlocation is selected)

The Following Is The Code Of SelectedIndexChanged:

```
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("IrisBin");
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> res = await query.FindAsync();
        List<int> list = new List<int>();

        foreach (var i in res)
        {
            var s = i.Get<int>("binHeight");

                list.Add(s);

                cbSelectArea.Items.Add(s).ToString();
                tbMaxVolume.Text = s.ToString();
                if (cbSelectArea.SelectedIndex == i.Get<int>("binHeight"))
                {
                }
                else
                {
                }
        }
        double maxHeight = Convert.ToDouble(tbMaxVolume.Text);
        double currentVol = Convert.ToDouble(tbCurrentVolume.Text);
        string results = CheckLevel(currentVol, maxHeight);
        lblAlertMessage.Text = results;
```

The Next One Is The Method To Be Displayed To The ComboBox:

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("IrisBin");
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> res = await query.FindAsync();
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    foreach (var i in res)
    {
        var s = i.Get<string>("binLocation");


        list.Add(s);
        cbSelectArea.Items.Add(s).ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Anyway I Manage To Somehow Figure It Out. Will Leave It Here Just In Case Someone Needs It.

Answer (score 0):

Adding To ComboBox

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("binInformation");
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> res = await query.FindAsync();
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    foreach (var i in res)
    {
        var s = i.Get<string>("binLocation");


        list.Add(s);


    }

    for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < list.Count; intCounter++)
    {
        object obj = list[intCounter];

        cbSelectArea.Items.Add(obj);
    }
```

SelectIndexChanged

```
var query = from gameScore in ParseObject.GetQuery("binInformation")
                    where gameScore.Get<string>("binLocation") == cbSelectArea.Text
                    select gameScore;
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();
        foreach (var i in results)
        {
            var s = i.Get<int>("binMaxCapacity");


            tbMaxVolume.Text = s.ToString();

        }
```